# GDAL -SQL or -where options

Tags: shapefile, gdal, coordinate-system, sql, ogr2ogr

ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3978 -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "SELECT * FROM 'Layer Name' WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'A CLASS'"  dst.shp src.shp

help me out here - looking to 
1) reproject a shape and 
2) select only "A CLASS" from field named "FIELD_NAME"
3) and save it to src.shp

my output is 
ERROR 1: Type mismatch or improper type of arguments to = operator.

I've also tried 
ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3978 -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "FIELD_NAME = 'A CLASS'"  dst.shp src.shp
resulting in:
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error
FAILURE: SetAttributeFilter( WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'A CLASSS') on layer 'LAYER NAME' failed.

and

ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3978 -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "FIELD_NAME LIKE 'A CLA%'"  dst.shp src.shp
with the las
which only produces one results, where 10,000+ records satisfy the query.

---

update

ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3978 -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT * FROM 'Layer Name' WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'A CLASS'"  dst.shp src.shp

yields 
ERROR 1: Type mismatch or improper type of arguments to = operator.
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_step(SELECT * FROM 'Layer Name' WHERE GIVEN_CLASS = 'Class A'):
  SQL logic error or missing database

one step closer though!

Comment: Try the first query by adding `-dialect=SQLite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the winner is to not use the = sign. this works for anyone looking..

ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3978 -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect SQLite -where "GIVEN_CLASS LIKE 'CLAS% A" dst src

indicating dialect + using -where + Like operator.